# PrimeNg selectButton: how to display one as selected

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an array of PrimeNg selectButtons and need to show the first one as pressed. 
Not finding any guidance on that.
Anyone know of the API to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to initialize the value of ngModel `[(ngModel)]="selectedCity"`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<p-selectButton [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-selectButton>'
})
export class AppComponent {

    selectedCity = 'London';

    cities: any[];

    ngOnInit() {

        this.cities = [                
            {label:'London', value:'London'},
            {label:'Istanbul', value:'Istanbul'},
            {label:'Paris', value:'Paris'}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I had that line dropped as part of my testing to really understand the code and sure enough I broke the code :( thank you

Answer (score 0):

or if u dont, just set selectedCity = null

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).